# SUMIFS formula in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I work in a logistics company and we do B2C deliveries for our client. So we have a rate card in a form of a table and list of deliveries/ transaction, the weight of the package and the location where it was delivered.

I have seen a lot of SUMIFS question being answered here but is very different from the one I need.

1st `transaction dataframe` contains `transaction id`, `weight`, `island`, `category`

```
transaction   weight   island   category
1             0.3      luzon    regular
2             0.5      visayas  express
3             0.5      luzon    express
4             0.4      visayas  regular
5             1.7      visayas  regular
6             1.5      luzon    regular
```

2nd `rate card dataframe`  contains `category`, `min_weight`,`max_weight`, `fee`

```
category    island  min weight  max weight  fee
regular     luzon     0            0.5       30
regular     luzon     0.51         3.0       40
express     luzon     0            3.0       45
regular     visayas   0            0.5       50
regular     visayas   0.51         3.0       60
express     visayas   0            3.0       65
```

So i want to calculate for the fee base on the weight of the package and the location. the resulting `transaction dataframe` should be

```
transaction      weight      island    category       fee
1                 0.3        luzon      regular        30
2                 0.5       visayas     express        65
3                 0.5        luzon      express        45
4                 0.4       visayas     regular        50
5                 1.7       visayas     regular        60
6                 1.5        luzon      regular        40
```

So here's the formula in `EXCEL` on how `fees` are calculated

```
=SUMIFS(rate_card.fee, rate_card.min_weight <= transaction.weight, rate_card.max_weight >= transaction.weight, rate_card.island = transaction.island, rate_card.category = transaction.category)
```

So i want to replicate this particular formula in `Python` using `Pandas`

Hopefully someone can provide a solution on my 1 month problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `category` and `island` and then [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) that `weight` from the `transaction` dataframe is between `min weight` and `max weight`:

```
new = transaction.merge(rate_card, on=['category', 'island'])\
                 .query('weight.between(`min weight`, `max weight`)')\
                 .sort_values('transaction')\
                 .drop(['min weight', 'max weight'], axis=1)
```

Or if your `pandas < 0.25.0`, it does not support the backtick column selection in `query` yet, then use:

```
new = transaction.merge(rate_card, on=['category', 'island'])

new = new.loc[new['weight'].between(new['min weight'], new['max weight'])]\
         .sort_values('transaction')\
         .drop(['min weight', 'max weight'], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   transaction  weight   island category  fee
0            1     0.3    luzon  regular   30
4            2     0.5  visayas  express   65
5            3     0.5    luzon  express   45
6            4     0.4  visayas  regular   50
9            5     1.7  visayas  regular   60
3            6     1.5    luzon  regular   40
```

---

**Details**:
The first merge gives us:

```
transaction.merge(rate_card, on=['category', 'island'])

   transaction  weight   island category  min weight  max weight  fee
0            1     0.3    luzon  regular        0.00         0.5   30
1            1     0.3    luzon  regular        0.51         3.0   40
2            6     1.5    luzon  regular        0.00         0.5   30
3            6     1.5    luzon  regular        0.51         3.0   40
4            2     0.5  visayas  express        0.00         3.0   65
5            3     0.5    luzon  express        0.00         3.0   45
6            4     0.4  visayas  regular        0.00         0.5   50
7            4     0.4  visayas  regular        0.51         3.0   60
8            5     1.7  visayas  regular        0.00         0.5   50
9            5     1.7  visayas  regular        0.51         3.0   60
```

Then we filter all the rows where `weight = between min weight, max weight`:

```
new = transaction.merge(rate_card, on=['category', 'island'])\
                 .query('weight.between(`min weight`, `max weight`)')

   transaction  weight   island category  min weight  max weight  fee
0            1     0.3    luzon  regular        0.00         0.5   30
3            6     1.5    luzon  regular        0.51         3.0   40
4            2     0.5  visayas  express        0.00         3.0   65
5            3     0.5    luzon  express        0.00         3.0   45
6            4     0.4  visayas  regular        0.00         0.5   50
9            5     1.7  visayas  regular        0.51         3.0   60
```

The last two steps are to sort correctly and to drop unnecessary columns

Comment: Hi @Erfan thank you for taking time on answering this question. I did run your solution line by line, the first line `transaction.merge(rate_card, on=['category', 'island'])` works fine, but i get an error with this line `.query('weight.between(`min weight`, `max weight`)')`.

Comment: Yes that probably because you have `pandas < 0.25.0`, you can check with `print(pd.__version__)`. Please check the second solution I provided, that one should work since it does not use `.query` and it will be many times faster than the other answer you accepted as correct since these are all vectorized methods. @lesterpaja

Comment: the second solution works! Thank you so much! I'll time both solutions with 100k transactions to see which is faster.

Comment: Cool, could you let me know, curious as well.@lesterpaja

Answer (score 1):

*Note*: Not a recommended solution (performance concerns), might be more useful for creating tests to make sure a better version using `merge` works as expected...

---

With the following preparation:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

transaction = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
transaction   weight   island   category
1             0.3      luzon    regular
2             0.5      visayas  express
3             0.5      luzon    express
4             0.4      visayas  regular
5             1.7      visayas  regular
6             1.5      luzon    regular
"""), sep=r"\s+")

rate = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
category    island  min_weight  max_weight  fee
regular     luzon     0            0.5       30
regular     luzon     0.51         3.0       40
express     luzon     0            3.0       45
regular     visayas   0            0.5       50
regular     visayas   0.51         3.0       60
express     visayas   0            3.0       65
"""), sep=r"\s+")
```

We can create a Pandas expression to calculate the sum of rates for the 1st transaction:

```
rate[(rate.min_weight <= 0.3) &
     (rate.max_weight >= 0.3) &
     (rate.island=="luzon") &
     (rate.category=="regular")].fee.sum()
```

And use that expression in a list comprehension for each row, then assign it to a new column like this:

```
transaction["fee"] = [
    rate[(rate.min_weight <= t.weight) &
         (rate.max_weight >= t.weight) &
         (rate.island == t.island) &
         (rate.category == t.category)].fee.sum()
    for t in transaction.itertuples()
]
```

Comment: Hi I've tried the given solution and it worked!! thanks a lot! may i know this particular line do: `for _, t in transaction.iterrows()`

Comment: [df.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) returns an iterable of pairs `(index, data)` and I am using [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=sequence%20unpacking#tuples-and-sequences) to assign the pair to 2 variables `_, t`, where the first one is just an underscore used as a convention for a variable name that won't be used for anything

Comment: after reading the above documentation, I simplified my code to use [`df.itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples)

Comment: This answer works, but iterating over a pandas dataframe is one of the things you should avoid, since we have vectorized solutions in `pandas` and `numpy`. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758) a good read on it